# Who voted for the Brexit deal bill but against the timetable?

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit, parliament, house-of-commons

Breaking news is that the Brexit deal bill passed its 2nd reading, but the timetable ("program motion", which would have allowed Brexit by the 31st) failed. So who voted for the 2nd reading but against the timetable? I don't necessarily want a list by MP name by more interestingly by parliamentary group (even more informal groups like "Brexiteer Labor" or ERG).

(Bercow just said that the technical term for the Brexit bill is "in limbo".)

Comment: Names here: https://www.theguardian.com/politics/blog/live/2019/oct/22/brexit-boris-johnson-deal-leave-eu-live-news https://www.theguardian.com/politics/ng-interactive/2019/oct/22/withdrawal-bill-how-did-your-mp-vote-on-the-timetable-motion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two useful sources:

The division list for the [Second Reading](https://hansard.parliament.uk/Commons/2019-10-22/division/C013EFF5-9D1E-4222-94E0-3E9386820C90/EuropeanUnion(WithdrawalAgreement)Bill?outputType=Party), grouped by Party.
The division list for the [Programming Motion](https://hansard.parliament.uk/Commons/2019-10-22/division/9FF7D3B1-6491-4922-A12F-2352FB53153B/EuropeanUnion(WithdrawalAgreement)Bill?outputType=Party), grouped by Party.

The only changes were:

1. 7 independents and 14 Labour MPs voting for second Reading but against the programming motion
2. One Labour MP (Kate Hoey) who seems to have missed the second reading division (she'd likely have voted FOR) and voted for the programming motion.
3. One Labour MP (Rosie Cooper) who voted against Second Reading but seems to have missed the programming motion vote. She'd presumably have voted no.

6 of the independents are pro-EU (or at least anti no-deal) ex-Conservatives who lost the whip - notably Ken Clarke and Phillip Hammond. The last of the independents is Stephen Lloyd, who is something of an oddity in this case. An ex-LibDem who specifically resigned because the party's policy on Brexit (stop it at all costs) breaches what he believes to be his commitment to his constituents to see Brexit through. That being the case, I presume he's concerned about the inability to scrutinise the WAB under the programming motion as moved.

For the Labour group it's slightly more diverse. They're mostly people who were not eurosceptic prior to the referendum and supported remain, but none that I recall openly calling for revoke. Mostly opponents of Corbyn, but that probably reflects the PLP generally. There's not really a firm grouping that I'm aware of.